# Unity - How to calculate BoxCollider's size fit to Mesh size

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an object with mesh like this.

[image]

Then attach BoxCollider Component to the object. It will appear BoxCollider Component with perfect position and perfect fit size and to the Mesh;

[image]

I am just curious, How Center and Size values come?
How to calculate them?

Thanks.

Comment: @Lece Thanks , anyway how the Center value come?